# Making background image load faster in an Angular app

Tags: css, angular, image-processing, optimization, sass

Tech: Angular v6, typescript and SASS.

I have a css background image for my homepage.
It's a large photo and never seems to load in time.

**CSS:**

```
@import '../../../scss/variables';

:host {
  .wrapper {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.5), rgba(0,0,0,.5)), url($hero-background) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;

  }
}
```

Is their any tricks I can try e.g. somehow preload the image.

**I had one attempt at this:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  public backgroundImg = './assets/backgrounds/hero20.jpg';
}
```

As you can see I tried to preload this in the main app.component.
This didnt really work though.

Comment: what do you mean "t's a large photo and never seems to load in time."

Comment: also when you say preload what do you mean?  load up before the route causes the view to show?

Comment: Basically when the website loads the homepage image takes three seconds to load

Answer (score 0):

would it be possible to remove that part of the page to outside of the Angular app and directly onto the page?  That would be one option that would definitely cause it to load earlier.

besides that I think you could enforce a stronger cache on the image, which of course would only have effect on non-initial visits, I think your best bet is removing it from the Angular load, OR looking into compressing or optimizing the image on a site such as:

https://compressor.io/